# 660 euro for portugal visa

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, tourist-visas, portugal

I will be applying 1st time for tourist schengen visa to portugal from india. presently I have balance of euro 660 for stay for 5-8 days including hotel expense. Is it enough so that visa do not reject. Also I have income tax return for last 2 years and not 3 years. I do not have any financial support except my salary. I am doing govt job, will that affect my visa chances? I will applying on my own and without any help of agency as they charge heavily, does it decrease your chances to get visa?

Comment: The balance is itself is within the guidelines but missing tax returns could be more of an issue and the consulate can also evaluate whether they think your income is appropriate.

Comment: Is 660 euros the total in the account, or a separate amount you have for the trip? If you're planning to use the majority of your savings for the trip, they're not going to like that.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [REFERENCE AMOUNTS REQUIRED FOR THE CROSSING OF THE EXTERNAL BORDER FIXED BY NATIONAL AUTHORITIES](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/docs/handbook-annex_25_en.pdf)

> Aliens must be in possession of the following amounts if they wish to
> enter or stay in Portugal:
>
> - EUR 75 – for each entry
> - EUR 40 – for each day spent on the territory
>
> Aliens who are able to prove that their board and lodging are guaranteed for the duration of
> their stay may be exempted from paying the above amounts.

So if you have 600 euro (75 euro per day for 8 days) - you fulfil the requirement.

Comment: To me, that reads as though he should have: 1 entry (75) and 8 days at 40/day (320), in total 395. (40/day seems a bit light to me, but...) Either way, it appears he has enough.

Comment: @simonatrcl correct; I took an extreme example to show s(he) has enough money.